# Minimization with Norm Constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I want to solve this minimization problem with Lagrange multiplier, but I face with one problem that it seems I need one equation more.
(A is a n*n matrix and B, u and x are n*1 vectors, I need to find u that minimizes equation)

$$ \min (1 + B(Ax+u)) \\
s.t \space \lVert u \rVert \leq 1 $$
For Lagrange function:
$$ B+ \lambda \frac{u^T}{\lVert u \rVert }=0\\
 \lVert u \rVert =1$$
After that:
$$ \lambda = -\frac{B}{u^T}$$
So here I don't have any more equation to find u.

Comment: how did you get $||u||=1$?

Comment: because ||u|| <= 1 is an active constraint and $$ \lambda $$ is not zero so it needs to ||u|| = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get $B+\lambda u^T=0$ and $||u||=1$, so
$$u = -\frac{1}{\lambda} B^T$$
so
$$\left\lVert \frac{1}{\lambda} B^T \right\rVert=1$$
so $\lambda = ||B^T||$, from which you can obtain $u$.